# Changing ModelChoiceField to ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a CreateView CBV where I override `get_form` to set a field type:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(EventMembershipCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['person'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.all(), to_field_name='email'
    )
    return form
```

This works fine when the field is `ModelChoiceField`, however I want to allow the users to create multiple objects which I will capture and `get_or_create` in `def post():`.

To do this, I change the field type to a multiple choice field set as `form.fields['person'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

However, even when submitting just one value on the form, I get the following error:

> ValueError at /lists/event/1/add/
>   Cannot assign "QuerySet Person: email@domain.com": "EventMembership.person" must be a "Person" instance.

The email input definitely is a Person instance, so I am not sure what is throwing this error.

Why does this `get_form` override work with `ModelChoiceField` and not `ModelMultipleChoiceField`?

Comment: `EventMembership.person` is a foreign key(?) and it does not make sense to pass multiple values to it and that is the error you are getting

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks, yes it is a foreignkey. What's the best practice approach to allow a user to create multiple objects with one form input? E.g. I have an input for an email and use Select2 to create tabs so the user can create several people.

Comment: A `CreateView` is probably not the place for something like that as a `CreateView` usually implies that you will just be creating 1 entry for that model. How are your models related and which model will you creating many of when the user passes multiple people?

Comment: This model (`EventMembership`) is a `though` model connecting a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Event` and `People`.  I want to allow users to bulk create memberships as they add emails into a single form select input. I am using Select2 to create tabable options so I can use one input.

Comment: Why not use an `UpdateView` for the `People` model? The form field that will be created for a many to many relationship (for a ModelForm) will accept multiple values and handle all the validation when you just call `form.save()`

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried that but unfortunately it prepopulates the existing relationships. I just want users to be able to create new relationships, not reconfirm existing ones too. I could prevent the prepopulation but assume it would they would be deleted on update?

Comment: Just a simple `FormView` would do then?

Comment: @IainShelvington unfortunately a plain FormView results in the same error.